# How to print test names in Leiningen?

Tags: unit-testing, clojure, leiningen

I would like to print each of my leiningen test methods as they are running. I have a lein tests file that is relatively simple:

```
(defn myfixture [b] 
  (do 
    (println "start") 
    (b)
    (println "end")
  )
)

(deftest test1 [] .....
```

I want to see "test1" print out at the repl when I run the tests.  Is there a simple way to print the method name (either by calling a method of b in myfixture, or, in the invocation of "lein test")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the name of a function like this:

```
(defn function-name [f]
  (:name (meta f))) 

(defn my-func []
   (println "Hello, world!"))

(let [f my-func]
  (function-name f))
;=> my-func
```

I don't know if the facility that you are looking for exists in the regular clojure.test but [midje](https://github.com/marick/Midje) has some pretty extensive fixture facilities, [this link](https://github.com/marick/Midje/wiki/Setup%2C-Teardown%2C-and-State) is maybe worth checking out.

Comment: Humm...    This did not  work.   This prints null,     (use-fixtures :each #(println " Function meta is " (meta %)))    When printed from "lein test" and added to the core_test.clj  (Not a lot of formatting options for comments.)